# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function with if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am having this code.

```
{
  Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {})).map((key) => {
    if (key !== "defaultOption" && customer[key] !== "") {
      return (
        <option key={key} value={key}>
          {_.startCase(key)}
        </option>
      );
    }
  });
}
```

And having below warning

```
  Line 885:96:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return
```

I know because I am using `if` statement inside the `map` function. So, How to get rid of the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014094/expected-to-return-a-value-at-the-end-of-arrow-function)

Comment: @wentjun Hmm. But got more innovative answers here.

Comment: Yup agree. Just adding more options for you to choose from :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return value outside of your if statement within your map function. Since you are not doing that you are being warned by eslint.

```
{
  Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {})).map((key) => {
    if (key !== "defaultOption" && customer[key] !== "") {
      return (
        <option key={key} value={key}>
          {_.startCase(key)}
        </option>
      );
    }
    return null;  // return value here 
  });
}
```

Now you can `return null` from within map function when your condition doesn't match as react doesn't render null values

Comment: Good to know that react doesn't return `null` values. I was afraid of that. But the `null` values still exists inside the array. Can be used inside the render but something else like filter.

Answer (score 3):

`return` something *after* the `if` statement (even if it is an empty string).

You might want to `filter` such values out of the array afterwards (or just `filter` the array first instead of using an `if`).

Answer (score 2):

What ESLint is telling you is that if the condition is false, your `map` callback doesn't return anything, so the array that `map` creates will have `undefined` there. That's often a mistake, rather than something you're doing intentionally.

Have the function return something whether the condition is true or false. For instance, you might return `null` if the condition is false, if you don't want React to render anything for that entry.

But instead, I'd probably `filter`, then `map`:

```
{
  Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {}))
  .filter((key) => key !== "defaultOption" && customer[key] !== "")
  .map((key) => (
      <option key={key} value={key}>
        {_.startCase(key)}
      </option>
    )
  )
}
```

---

Side note: I've removed the `;` after `map(/*...*/)` in the above because it looks like it's inside a JSX expression. `;` is a statement terminator, which you can't have inside a JSX expression. (Of course, if that isn't a JSX expression, ignore that change, though that would mean the code was creating `option`s that it never used... :-) )

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the problem is due to ***return statement being inside an if condition***.

This means that the function will return only when the condition is true.

The behaviour for condition being false also must be defined in order to resolve the issue.

This can be achieved in 3 ways:

- Add a filter to obtain only the interesting values in the map ***(Recommended)***
- Add an **else block** to return something when condition fails
- or by adding an explicit return at the final line of the code block.

**Here is an example of the suggested change:**

**Option 1:  Add a filter to get a map of interesting values only (recommended)**

```
Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {}))
    .filter( 
        (interestingValue) => (
            interestingValue !== "defaultOption" && 
            customer[interestingValue] !== ""
        ) 
    )
    .map( 
        (key) => (
            <option key={key} value={key}>
                {_.startCase(key)}
            </option>
        )
    )
```

**Option 2: Add an else block**

```
Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {}))
    .map( (key) => {
            if (key !== "defaultOption" && customer[key] !== "") {
                return (
                    <option key={key} value={key}>
                        {_.startCase(key)}
                    </option>
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <div>condition failed</div>
                )
            }            
        }
    )
```

**Option 3: Add an explicit return at the end of the block**

```
Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {}))
    .map( (key) => {
            if (key !== "defaultOption" && customer[key] !== "") {
                return (
                    <option key={key} value={key}>
                        {_.startCase(key)}
                    </option>
                )
            }
            return undefined
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You **have** to return something for `map()` to work with. You cannot 'skip' values with `map()`.

Try returning `null` and then applying `filter` to filter out those null values afterwards.

Comment: *"Try returning null and then applying filter to filter out those null values afterwards."* Better to filter them out before, I'd say, if you're going to filter anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add return null after if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is there is no `else block`, what if condition got `false`

**`map` function expects some value in returns**

```
{
  Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {})).map((key) => {
    if (key !== "defaultOption" && customer[key] !== "") {
      return (
        <option key={key} value={key}>
          {_.startCase(key)}
        </option>
      );
    } else { 
        return null;  // <----- You were missing this
    }
  });
}
```

**OR**

```
{
    Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {}))
    .filter((key) => (key !== "defaultOption" && customer[key] !== "") )
    .map((key) => (
        <option key={key} value={key}>
          {_.startCase(key)}
        </option>
      );
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this into a loop.

```
{
    (()=>{
        let arr=[];
        const keys = Object.keys(_.get(order, "customer", {}));
        for(let key of keys){
            if (key !== "defaultOption" && customer[key] !== "") {
                arr.push(<option key={key} value={key}>
                    {_.startCase(key)}
                </option>)
            }
        }
        return arr;
    })()
}
```

Comment: Well... Code is looking redundant and excessive.

Comment: However it is more editable and customizable due to the loop. Better than asking React to render `null` elements.