# Implicit return in arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a weird warning that I'm `Expected to return a value in arrow function` in the following code

```
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users")
        .then((res)=>{
            res.data.map(user => {                     <---- warning occurs here
                if(user.email === userData.email){
                    if(user.password === userData.password){
                        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
                        dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        .catch((err)=>dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.data
        }))
}
```

But I thought it was not required to declare an explicit `return` in an arrow function, what am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Comment: No, I'm having doubts on the arrow function

Comment: @Nimrod It doesn't need explicit return if it it is a single line statement.

Comment: try this `export const loginUser = (userData,dispatch) => `

Comment: No, I'm still getting the warning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014094/how-do-i-fix-expected-to-return-a-value-at-the-end-of-arrow-function-warning

Comment: add return `return dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));` or just return anything like `return user`

Comment: you should be using a `forEach` instead of `map`, there is no point to use `map` there since you don't plan to return anything.

Comment: Block bodied arrow functions require the `return` keyword to produce a value.

Comment: thanks, ```forEach``` removed the warning but is catching the error. I don't know why

Comment: The warning went away because the result of your previous `map()` would have been `[undefined,undefined,undefined ...]` which is very unlikely what any sane programmer wants so the linter complains about it. Foreach, unlike map, does not return a result so there is nothing wrong if you don't return anything to `forEach()`.

Answer (score 3):

For quick example when you are using map like this

```
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);
```

you no need to use an explicit return

but in scenario

```
const map1 = array1.map(x => {
return x*2
});
```

the main difference is due to flower brackets which expect a return statement.

The code you provided is doing dispatch action in this case it doesn't require anything to return, I would suggest using foreach loop
**[UPDATED]**

```
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users")
        .then((res)=>{
            res.data.foreach(user => {                     <---- warning occurs here
                if(user.email === userData.email){
                    if(user.password === userData.password){
                        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
                        dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        .catch((err)=>dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.data
        }))
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `return axios.get(...` so that callers can track the operation and handle errors?

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes we can do it but, in question it is pointed that Nimrod is facing warning at this statement res.data.map(user => {

Comment: I will also update my answer thanks for pointing @AluanHaddad

Comment: Right, but it's a good idea to forward the promise and it fits with the premise of your answers theme

Comment: @akhil using ```foreach``` removed the warning, but is catching the error, how could that happen?

Comment: @Nimrod you mean you are getting error in catch block?

Comment: Yes, how's that happening?

Comment: Is it because the promise is not being resolved, because nothing is being returned?

Comment: may be you are correct @Nimrod, can you try this one 



.catch((err)=>{dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.data
        })
        return Promise.reject()
      })
or 

.catch((err)=>{dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.data
        })
        return err;
      })

Comment: The answer uses `foreach` (lowercase "e") instead of `forEach` (uppercase "E"), maybe that causes an error? Btw the two `if`s can be combined with `&&`.